# Lightning component action executes Flow twice

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I have searched all around but cannot find out why My Lightning Action button seems to execute twice.  It executes a flow which creates a record and then redirects to a visualforce page.  But the issue is that it creates 2 copies of the new record...  I know that the "Init" function can get called multiple times if not implemented correctly...  What am I doing wrong here?

Lightning Component:

`<aura:component access="global" implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
</aura:component>`

Controller:

```
({
init : function (component) {
    console.log('init component ...');
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
    var inputvars = [{ name : "recordId", type : "String", value: component.get("v.recordId") }];
    flow.startFlow("New_Quote_Flow",inputvars);
},
handleStatusChange : function (component, event) {
   if(event.getParam("status") === "FINISHED") {
      var outputVariables = event.getParam("outputVariables");
      var outputVar;
      for(var i = 0; i < outputVariables.length; i++) {
         outputVar = outputVariables[i];
         if(outputVar.name === "QuoteId") {
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
               "url": "/apex/zqu__EditQuoteProducts?Id="+outputVar.value,
               "isredirect": "true"
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

})

This is my Lightning Action definition, if it helps:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't _anyone_ have some info on this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a lightning component that does a redirect and call it as an action as the last step from within the flow.

The component consists of these three parts

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:availableForFlowActions">
 <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({    
 invoke : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Get the record ID attribute
    var record = component.get("v.recordId");
   
    // Get the Lightning event that opens a record in a new tab
    var redirect = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    
    // Pass the record ID to the event
    redirect.setParams({
        "recordId": record
    });
    
    // Open the record
    redirect.fire();
}
})
```

Design:

```
<design:component>
 <design:attribute name="recordId" label="Record ID" />
</design:component>
```